# Shrinking my info box

Tags: html, css

I have an info box I am using that's made of HTML and CSS. I can't seem to figure out how to shrink the size of the boxes and the hover contents. Whenever I shrink the size of the boxes the hover content doesn't fit inside and I cant see what I am missing. Can anyone let me know how to change the size of my boxes properly? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}



.info-boxes li {
    width: 245px;
    height: 245px;
    background: #3299CC;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pics
{
  width:135px;
  height:135px;
}

.everything
{
  text-align:center;
}

.infobox-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 245px;
    width: 245px;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
    position: absolute;
    width: 245px;
    height: 245px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #a9bd38;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px 10px 0;
    transform: translateY(-240px);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    animation-name: windowshade-out;
      -webkit-animation-name: windowshade-out;
      -moz-animation-name: windowshade-out;
      -ms-animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
    animation-name: windowshade;
      -webkit-animation-name: windowshade;
      -moz-animation-name: windowshade;
      -ms-animation-name: windowshade;
}

.info-boxes li .shade, 
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
      -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
      -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);  
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

section p {
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #6d6e71;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.infobox img {margin-bottom:7px}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position:absolute;
  width:245px;
  height:245px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color:#4682B4;
  color:#fff;
  display:table;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:20px 10px 0;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px);
  animation-name:windowshade-out
    -webkit-animation-name:windowshade-out;
    -moz-animation-name:windowshade-out;
    -ms-animation-name:windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {color:#fff;padding:10px;font-weight:bold}
.info-boxes li .shade p {color:#fff;line-height:1.4em;font-weight:normal}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade{
  -webkit-animation-name:windowshade;
  -moz-animation-name:windowshade;
  -ms-animation-name:windowshade;
  animation-name:windowshade}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {top:245px}
.info-boxes li:hover a {text-decoration:none}

@-webkit-keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@-moz-keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@-ms-keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}

@-moz-keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}

@-ms-keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}

@keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="everything">
<section class="info-boxes">
  <ul class="infobox-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <img class="pics" src=""><br>
                    </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <h3>My Profile</h3>
          <p>Get real-time feedback to improve products, services, and business overall</p>
          <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <img class="pics" src=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <h3>My Performance</h3>
          <p>Assess the key drivers of talent retention to build an effective company culture</p>
          <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
                <a href="/mp/event-planning-surveys/?ut_source=homepage&amp;ut_source2=home_oz_uk"><div class="infobox"><img class="pics" src=""><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
                        <h3>My Learning</h3>
                        <p>Gather attendee feedback to perfect the planning process and win more contracts</p>
                        <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    <li>
<a href="/mp/education-surveys/?ut_source=homepage&amp;ut_source2=home_oz_uk">
   <div class="infobox"><img class="pics" src=""><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
                        <h3>My Team</h3>
                        <p>Get answers to improve programs, processes, and academic achievement</p>
                        <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>      
</ul> 
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve here? I didn't get it

Comment: _Whenever I shrink the size of the box_, what box? Please use selectors to specify what box you'll say.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn I am just wondering on how I change the sizes of all the boxes. I want to make them smaller. But when I make them smaller, the hover content falls out of place.

Comment: Currently 245x245. What would you want them to be?

Comment: What happens with the content inside the "box" if the "box" is smaller and the content has not enough space inside?

Comment: @Gerard around 150

Comment: You don't need to use `-webkit-margin-*` or `-webkit-padding-*`, using regular old `margin` and `padding` will override those user agent values.

Comment: @hungerstar will that fix the issue I am having?

Comment: No, simply it's unnecessary to use `-webkit-margin-*` and `-webkit-padding-*` properties. It's not the same as the other browser prefixed attributes.

Comment: @hungerstar Oh alright, thanks for that. Do you know how to resize the boxes?

Comment: Well, you might want to be a little more clear on why the boxes need to be smaller and what your expectations are for the box, box overlay content etc. If making the boxes smaller causes the overlay content not fit then you have maybe three choices; 1) resize the content so it fits, i.e. smaller font size, 2) hide some of the content or 3) if 1 and 2 are no goes then you're probably as small as you can go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adjusted the size to 150x150 and adjusted the font size to make the text fit.
Duplicate CSS removed.

```css
.infobox-list {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul,
ol,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul,
li,
ol,
form,
fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
menu,
dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
  min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #3299CC;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* margin: 0 20px 40px; */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pics {
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  /* margin-bottom: 7px; */
  max-width: 100%;
}

.everything {
  text-align: center;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #a9bd38;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateY(-150px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-150px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: windowshade-out;
  -moz-animation-name: windowshade-out;
  -ms-animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
  -webkit-animation-name: windowshade;
  -moz-animation-name: windowshade;
  -ms-animation-name: windowshade;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: normal
}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  -webkit-animation-name: windowshade;
  -moz-animation-name: windowshade;
  -ms-animation-name: windowshade;
  animation-name: windowshade
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@-webkit-keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    transform: translateY(-240px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">
  <section class="info-boxes">
    <ul class="infobox-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <img class="pics" src="">
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <h3>My Profile</h3>
            <p>Get real-time feedback to improve products, services, and business overall</p>
            <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png">
            <br>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <img class="pics" src="">
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <h3>My Performance</h3>
            <p>Assess the key drivers of talent retention to build an effective company culture</p>
            <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png">
            <br>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/mp/event-planning-surveys/?ut_source=homepage&amp;ut_source2=home_oz_uk">
          <div class="infobox"><img class="pics" src="">
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <h3>My Learning</h3>
            <p>Gather attendee feedback to perfect the planning process and win more contracts</p>
            <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png">
            <br>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/mp/education-surveys/?ut_source=homepage&amp;ut_source2=home_oz_uk">
          <div class="infobox"><img class="pics" src="">
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <h3>My Team</h3>
            <p>Get answers to improve programs, processes, and academic achievement</p>
            <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png">
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/6075pwhk/)

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood you right: you want to have your boxes and everything inside it smaller? well, you used px values in a lot of different places for the size (and sometimes in the translates) so you'd have to change them according to the size you want them to be.

you could also just scale them down:

```
.info-boxes li {
// your other stuff
transform: scale(.9);           
}
```

here's the updated code:

```css
.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}



.info-boxes li {
    width: 245px;
    height: 245px;
    background: #3299CC;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(.9);
}

.pics
{
  width:135px;
  height:135px;
}

.everything
{
  text-align:center;
}

.infobox-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 245px;
    width: 245px;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
    position: absolute;
    width: 245px;
    height: 245px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #a9bd38;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px 10px 0;
    transform: translateY(-240px);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-240px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-240px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-240px);
    animation-name: windowshade-out;
      -webkit-animation-name: windowshade-out;
      -moz-animation-name: windowshade-out;
      -ms-animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
    animation-name: windowshade;
      -webkit-animation-name: windowshade;
      -moz-animation-name: windowshade;
      -ms-animation-name: windowshade;
}

.info-boxes li .shade, 
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
      -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
      -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);  
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
      -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

section p {
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: #6d6e71;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.infobox img {margin-bottom:7px}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position:absolute;
  width:245px;
  height:245px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color:#4682B4;
  color:#fff;
  display:table;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:20px 10px 0;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px);
  animation-name:windowshade-out
    -webkit-animation-name:windowshade-out;
    -moz-animation-name:windowshade-out;
    -ms-animation-name:windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {color:#fff;padding:10px;font-weight:bold}
.info-boxes li .shade p {color:#fff;line-height:1.4em;font-weight:normal}

.info-boxes li:hover .shade{
  -webkit-animation-name:windowshade;
  -moz-animation-name:windowshade;
  -ms-animation-name:windowshade;
  animation-name:windowshade}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {top:245px}
.info-boxes li:hover a {text-decoration:none}

@-webkit-keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@-moz-keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@-ms-keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes windowshade{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
  transform:translateY(-240px)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0);
    -ms-transform:translateY(0);
    transform:translateY(0)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}

@-moz-keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}

@-ms-keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}

@keyframes windowshade-out{
  0%{
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
  -moz-transform:translateY(0);
  -ms-transform:translateY(0);
  transform:translateY(0)}
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-240px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-240px);
    transform:translateY(-240px)}
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="everything">
<section class="info-boxes">
  <ul class="infobox-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <img class="pics" src=""><br>
                    </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <h3>My Profile</h3>
          <p>Get real-time feedback to improve products, services, and business overall</p>
          <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <img class="pics" src=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <h3>My Performance</h3>
          <p>Assess the key drivers of talent retention to build an effective company culture</p>
          <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
                <a href="/mp/event-planning-surveys/?ut_source=homepage&amp;ut_source2=home_oz_uk"><div class="infobox"><img class="pics" src=""><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
                        <h3>My Learning</h3>
                        <p>Gather attendee feedback to perfect the planning process and win more contracts</p>
                        <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    <li>
<a href="/mp/education-surveys/?ut_source=homepage&amp;ut_source2=home_oz_uk">
   <div class="infobox"><img class="pics" src=""><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
                        <h3>My Team</h3>
                        <p>Get answers to improve programs, processes, and academic achievement</p>
                        <img src="https://secure.surveymonkey.com/smassets/anonweb/anonweb/0.0.0.709/assets/homepage/link-arrow-white.png"><br>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>      
</ul> 
</section>
</div>
```